# How to determine account_id and region from a query?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have datasets that are pulling from multiple Amazon RDS servers in multiple accounts, and I'd really like to be able to have the SQL Server instance tell me which account owns it and which region it lives in.

For example, this would be ideal when constructing ARNs on the fly:

```sql
SELECT id, 'arn:aws:quicksight:' + rdsadmin.dbo.get_region() +
    ':' + rdsadmin.dbo.get_account_id() + ':group/default/admin' AS groupArn
FROM my_rules_table
```

I've looked all over and I don't see a way to infer this information. I could create unique versions of those UDFs on every server with static values, but I'd really rather fetch the actual values dynamically.

EDIT:
Another way to think about my request is that I want to do in Amazon RDS what I can do in all my other EC2 instances:

```sh
read -r account_id region <<< $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r '. | "\(.accountId) \(.region)"')
echo "arn:aws:quicksight:$region:$account_id:group/default/admin"
```

This is just a workaround because Amazon QuickSight has certain requirements on the supported SQL features used to fetch data.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything like this. The database doesn't know anything about its environment, it just knows about itself. The URL used to access the database should give a hint about the Region, but that is invisible from an SQL perspective. Perhaps you could add a table to each database with those static values?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I suspect you're right. I'm just hoping that somehow this data is exposed where I haven't looked yet. I'd rather not put the values in a table because copies and replicas will cause those rows to reappear in new places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find the information exposed from Amazon RDS for Microsoft® SQL Server®, so I created a table to hold this information in each RDS instance:

```
CREATE TABLE rds_instance (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEWID()),
    account_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    environment VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The values for `account_id`, `environment`, and `region` can be plugged in and used where needed. A copied database can be programmatically modified for its new placement:

```
UPDATE rds_instance SET active = 0;
INSERT INTO rds_instance (account_id, environment, region, active)
VALUES ('12341234123', 'stage', 'us-southwest-7', 1);
```

The instance information can be used to produce ARNs in a query like so:

```
SELECT u.fkid, 'arn:aws:quicksight:' + ri.region + ':' + ri.account_id +
    ':user/' + ri.environment + '_ns/' + u.username AS userArn
FROM users AS u
    JOIN rds_instance AS ri ON (ri.active = 1)
```